# How to add event to a button in gridview, which will carry the respective row data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm creating a student management system where i want to enable student to pay online, by clicking the pay button in the Fee table grideview i want student to direct to another page which will show what he has selected in the gridview and invoice no can be aotogenerated

Comment: You don't need to apologize for creating a student management system but for not showing us anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your `gidview` selected data in `datatable` variable on button click and store that `datatable` in `session` before redirect to another page. After redirect to another page you just create one `datatable` variable on redirected page load event and assign `session` value to that variable by type casting.